# How can i make scrapy look for and fetch specific words on older webpages that dont have css tags around a paragraph

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I figured out how to actually extract specific text but now I can't seem to figure out how to do it when there is no text tag. [If you look at the structure of this page in your browsers dev tools](https://scholarships.uottawa.ca/p/a/224734/) you can see that there's no actual  tags for the text, the only tags are  for the title. Let's say I want to extract the text under PURPOSE OF FUND. How would I go about telling Scrapy to get just the text under the PURPOSE OF FUND and nothing else?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import scrapy

class uOttawaGrantSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ottawa-grant_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://scholarships.uottawa.ca/p/a/224734/']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.left'
        for grants in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            pass

            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h2 ::text'
            DESC_SELECTOR = './/clearfix[strong/text() = "PURPOSE OF FUND"]/text()'
            yield {
                'name': grants.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'desc': grants.xpath(DESC_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.re` method and apply a regex as follows ->

```py
import scrapy

class uOttawaGrantSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ottawa-grant_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://scholarships.uottawa.ca/p/a/224734/']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.left'
        for grants in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
          

            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h2 ::text'
            desc = grants.re(r"PURPOSE OF FUND\<\/strong\>\<br\>\r\n[\w*,*\s?]*")[0]     
            desc = desc.replace("PURPOSE OF FUND\<\/strong\>\<br\>\r\n", "") 
            yield {
                'name': grants.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'desc': desc
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try XPath `//div[@class='clearfix']/strong[contains(., 'PURPOSE OF FUND')]/following-sibling::text()[1]`
Sorry I usually use rvest (R), I'm not very familiar with Scrapy and Python so I can't privide the code.